# Powershell Regex - extract string between two given characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I am a regex/powershell beginner and struggling to get this working. I am working with some HTML data and I need to be able to extract the string between given characters. In the below case, I need to extract the string (if it matches my search string) which is found between the characters **> and <**. I have provided multple examples here and I hope I made my question clear. Any help is greatly appreciated.

For example -

```
$string1 = '<P><STRONG><SPAN style="COLOR: rgb(255,0,0)">ILOM 2.6.1.6.a <BR>BIOS vers. 0CDAN860 <BR>LSI MPT SAS firmware MPT BIOS 1.6.00</SPAN></STRONG></P></DIV></TD>'

$string2 = '<P><A id=T5220 name=T5220></A><A href="http://mywebserver/index.html">Enterprise T5120 Server</A> <BR><A href="http://mywebserver/index.html">Enterprise T5220 Server</A></P></DIV></TD>'


$searchstring = "ILOM"
$regex = ".+>(.*$searchstring.+)<" # Tried this
$string1 -match $regex
$matches[x] = ILOM 2.6.1.6.a  # expected result
```

Similarly -

```
$searchstring = "BIOS"
$regex = ".+>(.*$searchstring.+)<" # Tried this
$string1 -match $regex
$matches[x] = BIOS vers. 0CDAN860  # expected result

$searchstring = "T5120"
$regex = ".+>(.*$searchstring.+)<" # Tried this
$string2 -match $regex
$matches[x] = Enterprise T5120 Server   # expected result

$searchstring = "T5220"
$regex = ".+>(.*$searchstring.+)<" # Tried this
$string2 -match $regex
$matches[x] = Enterprise T5220 Server  # expected result
```

Comment: [No Regex for HTML!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2359643)  Use a HTML parser.

Comment: What is `$matches[x]` currently returning?

Comment: `$matches[1]` currently matches `ILOM 2.6.1.6.a <BR>BIOS vers. 0CDAN860 <BR>LSI MPT SAS firmware MPT BIOS 1.6.00</SPAN></STRONG></P></DIV>` for my 1st example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the lazy `?` operator(? qualifier?) on the "wildcard" after your searchstring to make it stop at the first occurence of `<`.

```
.*< = Any character as many as possible until an <

.*?< = Any character until first <
```

I would use the lazy operator on the "wildcard" before your searchstring too just to be safe even though it isn't necessary in this particular situation.

The minimum required modification:

```
".+>(.*$searchstring.+?)<"
```

I would recommend:

```
".+>(.*?$searchstring.+?)<"
```

Sample:

```
$string1 = '<P><STRONG><SPAN style="COLOR: rgb(255,0,0)">ILOM 2.6.1.6.a <BR>BIOS vers. 0CDAN860 <BR>LSI MPT SAS firmware MPT BIOS 1.6.00</SPAN></STRONG></P></DIV></TD>'

$string2 = '<P><A id=T5220 name=T5220></A><A href="http://mywebserver/index.html">Enterprise T5120 Server</A> <BR><A href="http://mywebserver/index.html">Enterprise T5220 Server</A></P></DIV></TD>'


$searchstring = "ILOM"
$regex = ".+>(.*?$searchstring.+?)<"
if($string1 -match $regex) { $matches[1] }

#Custom regex
$searchstring = "BIOS"
$regex = ".+>($searchstring.+?)<"
if($string1 -match $regex) { $matches[1] }

#Or the original regex with different search string
$searchstring = "BIOS vers"
$regex = ".+>(.*?$searchstring.+?)<"
if($string1 -match $regex) { $matches[1] }

$searchstring = "T5120"
$regex = ".+>(.*?$searchstring.+?)<"
if($string2 -match $regex) { $matches[1] }

$searchstring = "T5220"
$regex = ".+>(.*?$searchstring.+?)<"
if($string2 -match $regex) { $matches[1] }
```

Output:

```
ILOM 2.6.1.6.a 
BIOS vers. 0CDAN860 
BIOS vers. 0CDAN860 
Enterprise T5120 Server
Enterprise T5220 Server
```

Comment: Thanks @Frode F. However it doesn't work with my second example. I was wanting it to match with "BIOS vers. 0CDAN860".

Comment: That requires a different regex or searchstring. updated with 2 BIOS examples now.